# Question views vs. answers

Tags: discussion

So, it looks like people are looking at the questions that are asked, but not answering them—it seems like it's roughly 30 views per answer. We're also not getting very many answers per question—generally one, sometimes two, rarely more than that. My feeling is that more answers will lead to more engagement with the site, as people discuss the answers in comments and provide counter-answers to each other's answers. What would encourage more folks to give answers? Is the problems just that questions are being asked that so few people have answers to?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that many of the views are coming in from internet searches. The people looking don't have accounts, so they are not adding to the answers.

There is also the human issue, of noobs creating second answers to questions.  They are afraid they will get [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBITE).

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with James' observation that there is a basic threshold of views per day coming from search engines, how many those are I don't know.

I have tried to view each question, initially within a few hours, later every few days because of the low frequency. I just found out I missed at least one question in April that I could have so easily answered (and only because it got another answer here today and was on the Active list did I see it). Maybe I should see if the system can notify me of new issues (it probably can).

As for the issue of second and more questions, this might have to do with the subject of the site. The ebook-readers are devices with just a few dimensions for problems, compared e.g. to making a computer program or managing a Unix system. That leads to problems with more single answers as these are more obviously correct and those don't trigger additional answers. This doesn't apply to all subjects on this site, but IMHO it brings the average down.